# App as a desktop environment (Linux)

Tags: linux, desktop-application, desktop

Want to make the desktop environment as the application.
Is it possible?
No need to say that I need a window Manager and other things... I know that it is easier to write on Qt, but I need it to run the application as the environment.

Comment: Do you need your application to be able to render and deal with other applications as "windows" in your window manager? If you're not dealing with windows in any other frameworks, you might be able to get away with a fullscreen application running on a different window manager.

Comment: I want to make something like a distribution game. In this case, I cannot use a third-party window managers, DE and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could spend *many* months or more probably *several years* diving into the details of [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) and of [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html).

I don't think it is worth your efforts, notably because several Linux distributions are giving up X11 in favor of [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845734/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887959/841108)

I recommend using [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [SDL](http://libsdl.org/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), even for a game.

Comment: Suppose I have a application that runs on X.org and I'm not sure it will work with ease on Wayland.

Comment: An application which uses `Qt` will run on X11 and on Wayland.